# MIP SDK 1.7.133 .NET Core 3.1 support

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, microsoft-information-protection

I created a new .NET Core 3.1 project and installed the MIP SDK 1.7.133 via nuget

I wrote some code to fetch the sensitivity labels and it all works fine, but I keep getting this warning that the MIP SDK package may not support .NET Core 3.1 (although it works)

```
warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.InformationProtection.File 1.7.133' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: this package only supports classic .net framework 4.x

Comment: So why they say it now supports .NET Core? 

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-and/microsoft-information-protection-sdk-1-7-now-available/ba-p/1686076

".NET Core Support
A common question we've received since shipping support for .NET has been "is .NET Core supported?" In this release, we're pleased to report that you can now install the MIP File SDK NuGet package on .NET Core projects in both Windows and Ubuntu 18.04. Install via NuGet today!"

Comment: the ubuntu version is .net standard 2.0 compatible and can be consumed from .net core projects

Comment: And what about the Windows version?

Comment: see the answer from Microsoft, this was a bug

Comment: Yes I saw. Will wait for the fix. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies. This is a bug in the package. We plan to fix and release an update this month.

Comment: @tom-moser, any news about the release date ? This warning is quite annoying.

Comment: Apologies on the delay. I've just uploaded the packages and they should be available for use shortly.